# How to write a startsWith list function using an Active Pattern instead of when guard?

Tags: f#, guard-clause

I need to check if a list starts with another, shorter list. The function, when using **when** guards is trivial:

```
let rec startsWith l1 l2 =
  match l1, l2 with
  | [], _ | _, [] -> true
  | x::xs, y::ys when x = y -> startsWith xs ys
  | _ -> false

let lst1 = [ 1; 2; 1 ]
let lst2 = [ 1; 2; 1; 2; 3; ]
let lst3 = [ 1; 3; 1; 2; 3; ]

let c1 = startsWith lst1 lst2  // true
let c2 = startsWith lst1 lst3  // false
```

But whatever I tried along the lines of an Active Pattern:

```
let (|HeadsMatch|) (l1 : ('a) list) (l2 : ('a) list) = 
  if l1.Head = l2.Head then Some(l1.Tail, l2.Tail) else None

let rec startsWith l1 l2 =
   match l1, l2 with
   | [], _ | _, [] -> true
   | HeadsMatch /* need to capture the result */ -> startsWith t1 t2
   | _ -> false
```

I could not make to compile. How to make a version of this function using Active pattern? And if this is not possible, can you explain why?

P.S. Any other nice ways to write the above function?

EDIT: I took the snippet from Daniel's answer to not distract from the real question.

EDIT: My problems started in the beginning. I have defined the active pattern function as

```
let (|HeadsMatch|_|) lst1 lst2 =
```

but it should have been

```
let (|HeadsMatch|_|) (lst1, lst2) =
```

In which case it would match as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose the *nicest* way might be

```
let startsWith = Seq.forall2 (=)
```

If you want to write it from scratch, you need to match on both lists:

```
let rec startsWith l1 l2 =
  match l1, l2 with
  | [], _ | _, [] -> true
  | x::xs, y::ys when x = y -> startsWith xs ys
  | _ -> false
```

If you want to write it with an active pattern for learning purposes, using [Tarmil's definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22791207/162396) it would be

```
let rec startsWith l1 l2 =
  match l1, l2 with
  | [], _ | _, [] -> true
  | HeadsMatch(xs, ys) -> startsWith xs ys
  | _ -> false
```

Comment: forall2 one throws because of different lengths

Comment: It's fixed. That should be `Seq.forall2`, which ignores the remaining elements of the longer list.

Comment: Some people frown at when guard and say an Active pattern is a way to avoid it. This is what my question is about.

Comment: The syntax for pattern matching lists is really rich to begin with so an active pattern seems especially superfluous in this context. You asked if there's "another nice way to write" your function. That's the part of the question I hoped to address.

Comment: Even though `when` guards and active patterns can be used to solve the same problem, (i.e, handling complex checks that can't be expressed with a pattern) their purposes seem mostly orthogonal in my view. But, in this context, you could generally follow the rule that a condition involving more than a handful of logical operators should be moved to an active pattern. When all else fails, judge by readability.

Comment: I like this answer, but what prompted me to post the question is that I could not make the active pattern work AT ALL, no matter how ugly I made it ;) This is a learning experiment, and I need to either know that what I tried is not possible or see a way to do it. Single case, parameterized - whatever, but I understand that Active Patterns are a superset of when guards.

Comment: @SergeyAldoukhov: The short answer is an active pattern is excessive for this kind of list matching. But Tarmil showed how you can write it if you're just trying to learn.

Comment: Nope, he did not. He wrote an active pattern function, but did not use it to write the function in question. To your comment - I agree it is excessive, but can it be done?

Comment: Oh, now I see what was wrong - if I would use a tuple as a parameter to active pattern instead of two lists, it would work. Lesson learned.

Comment: You might benefit from reading the last section (_Parameterized Active Patterns_) of the [Active Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors in the definition of your active pattern:

1. It's a partial active pattern (since it is possible that it doesn't match) so the syntax is `(|HeadsMatch|_|)`.
2. You need to take the two lists as a pair, since you want to match `lst1, lst2`.

With these, the code will compile. But it will throw an exception at runtime, because you use `.Head` and `.Tail` on lists when you don't know if they have any element; you're not defining the behavior if one of the lists is empty.

Here is an idiomatic implementation of `HeadsMatch`:

```
let (|HeadsMatch|_|) (lst1, lst2) =
    match (lst1, lst2) with
    | (x :: xs, y :: ys) when x = y -> Some (xs, ys)
    | _ -> None
```

Without guard:

```
let (|HeadsMatch|_|) (lst1, lst2) =
    match (lst1, lst2) with
    | (x :: xs, y :: ys) ->
        if x = y then Some (xs, ys) else None
    | _ -> None
```

As a side-note, your first implementation has the same problem. The following will throw a runtime exception:

```
startsWith [1;2] [1]
```

because you don't check that `lst2` is not empty before using `.Head` and `.Tail` on it. In general, *you should avoid these two methods almost all the time*.

Comment: By definition, the first list is shorter, so my implementation will not throw. But the question is about using an active pattern without when guard.

Comment: I'd still avoid having unchecked preconditions as much as possible. How do you make sure that you will indeed never have a longer first list? What if the requirements on the caller change? What if in the future you try to use it from a function that has no such guarantees? This kind of "I know I'll always call it with the right arguments" is a time bomb.

Comment: Note taken. Still, the question stands.

Comment: I added an implementation without guard, but I fail to see how it's in any way better.

Comment: You have implemented an Active pattern function. What I want is a version of startsWith implemented using patter matching via active pattern and not using when guard.

Comment: Sorry for not paying enough attention to your #2 - if I could mark two answers as a correct one I would do so.